# Meter Number, Key, Password Fields Missing for FedEx Setup

Tags: error, fedex, setup

I am trying to add FedEx as a shipping option in Magento UPS is currently enabled. I have registered, have my production password, FedEx account number, production meter number and production URL. However, there is no place to enter these, only Title, Gateway URL and Account ID is showing up. Is the production URL the same thing as Gateway URl? See attached snippet of what I am seeing. Much thanks in advance.[image: FedEx Setup in Magento]